# Winform in C# stopped displaying unicode Chinese characters

Tags: c#, winforms, unicode, fonts

I have a strange Unicode character displaying behavior in Visual Studio 2010 C# Winform. I'm using Windows 7 x64. For some reason I was able to do something like this in the code and got the character to display correctly when pressing the button.  The font was the default Microsoft Sans Serif.

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    button1.Text = "Initialize System 初始化系统";
  }
```

However, after I closed down the project and re-open it the button now only displays 2 squares as if the characters are missing.  I don't understand what could have changed and why it had worked the first time.

Some posts suggested using MS Gothic for the control, but for some reasons I can't even choose that in the properties window.  The font is in my system since I checked in control panel -> Font.  MS Gothic was there.

Is there some settings that could have changed the font settings in the winform to allow MS Gothic font?

The only way I could get this to work now is to override the paint event of the button and then do the rendering there.  This is more difficult to do on component like DataGrid though. This is the code that works for the button with Chinese characters:

```
private void _Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
  Button btn = (Button)sender;
  SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(btn.ForeColor);
  StringFormat sf = new StringFormat { Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,
                                       LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center };
  string text = "Initialize System 初始化系统";
  btnIntialize.Text = string.Empty;
  e.Graphics.DrawString(text, btn.Font, drawBrush, e.ClipRectangle, sf);
  drawBrush.Dispose();
  sf.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: MS Gothic is for Japanese, not Chinese, so you will need a different font regardless (which one depends on whether you're using traditional or simplified Chinese).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're using Simplified Chinese characters and not Japanese, the correct font is SimSun or Ms Song.

Microsoft sometimes automatically switches the font for you, for example when you copy-paste that initializing text into Word you'll see that the English part is written in Arial or the like and the Chinese text was automatically switched to SimSun or whatever is the default Chinese font on your computer. I imagine this is what happened when the text was displayed correctly at first. Then, when saving the project it had the problem that one button caption cannot be in two different fonts, so it saved the button font as Microsoft Sans Serif and is now giving you square boxes because of that. The solution is to use SimSun or Ms Song for the button, because these fonts can display both English and Chinese characters. You will encounter a problem if you want the same button to also display German or Korean or the like though. If that is the case, you will need to dynamically set the button font depending on the localization language.

Comment: You are absolutely correct about this.  It seems like a strange behavior for the Visual Studio IDE to let me do that since the Simplified Chinese characters are not even a part of the default Arial font, or the Sans Serif.  Another weird quirk I found was that if you use the "..." button to browse for the fonts you won't find the fonts like SimuSun, or SimHei.  However, if you expand the Font field using the arrow, you can select these fonts by choosing the the "Name" field.  So strange.