# Japanese characters showing ? sign

Tags: c#, winforms, unicode

I have a winform application with the use of Segoe UI font. In Windows 10, Japanese character are displayed correctly. But, Windows 7 is displaying the characters as ? sign. What is the cause of this problem and how can I solve this issue?

Comment: This can be silly question but did you installed Japanese language pack? [Or done this trick](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/how-can-i-get-chinesejapanese-characters-to/fdb1f1da-b868-40d1-a4a4-7acadff4aafa)

Comment: Similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007411/winform-in-c-sharp-stopped-displaying-unicode-chinese-characters. Seems that you need to include (and install) fonts used in UI to target machine. If your Win 7 is Japanese version without additional language pack, be aware that sometimes it switches the font automatically depending on usage.

Answer (score 7):

The reason is that the Segoe UI font is <s>not preinstalled</s> (see edit below) on Windows 7 so it probably falls back to a different font which might not support Japanese character set.

You have two (three) options:

- Use a different font which is supported on both Windows 10 and Windows 7
- Check for the system version and change the font at runtime
- (not use Windows 7 :-) )

**Edit**

It seems I was mistaken - Segoe UI [actually is a part of Windows 7](http://viziblr.com/news/2009/5/3/beautiful-new-segoe-ui-fonts-in-windows-7.html), it was just not used as the default font for the Classic theme (there was the default Tahoma), only for Aero.

In that case you probably need to **install the Japanese language pack** to enable japanese characters on Windows 7.

Comment: Is Windows 7 default window font Segoe UI?

Comment: Interesting fact I have just now discovered - Segoe UI actually was present in Windows 7 (http://viziblr.com/news/2009/5/3/beautiful-new-segoe-ui-fonts-in-windows-7.html).
The default system font was Tahoma.
It seems in this case that either the Japanese charset support is missing or you actually need that Japanese language pack to be able to display Japanese characters.

Answer (score 2):

Just go to the Region in Control Panel, In Administrative Tab, Change system locale to Japanese.

And Restart

Comment: Windows 7 is the Japanese windows.

Comment: I use Persian language, that is a problem i always have.